# How to deal with doing the same thing multiple times

Tags: android

I got a button that gets the text from some edit texts, and does some calculation on them depending on what option was choose from spinner, so there is a lot of code in on Click and i need to use it 3 times

At the moment my code looks something like this

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("blk")) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // a lot of code here
                }
            });
        } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Length")) {
            edtNumber1.setText(setLength + "");

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // do the same here
                }
            });
        } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Height")) {
            edtNumber2.setText(setHeight + "");

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // do the same here
                }
            });
```

How do I shorten up this code, I find myself doing this a lot repeating the same code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your ActivityClass to implement `View.OnClickListener()`

Now for each button set `onClickListener()` as ->

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Implement onClickListener as ->

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do common work here and if you want to do different work then ->
    switch(v.getId())
    {
      case R.id.btn:
                    //TODO Code
                    break;
      case R.id.something:
                    break;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Luksprog mentioned in comments, create a method that you can reuse:

```
private void doALotOfWork() {
    // do a lot of work here
}
```

And call it everywhere it's needed:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    doALotOfWork();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your Activity to implement `OnClickListener` and override `onClick()` appropriately.

Then you only need to call `btn.setOnClickListener(this);` and you only need to call it once.

If you have many Views that call your Activity's onClick method, you can do a switch on `view.getId()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a method to do it if you don't want to implement an interface.

```
    setButtonListener(Button btn) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            whenButtonGetsClicked();

        }
    });
}

whenButtonGetsClicked(){
    //do your magic
}
```

However, i recommend using an interface to do it as described by Tanix.7x

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way for me:

```
OnClickListener buttonListener=new OnClickListener()  {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
      // a lot of code here
  }
}

if (getIntent().hasExtra("blk")) {
  btn.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
} else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Length")) {
  edtNumber1.setText(setLength + "");
  btn.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
} else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Height")) {
   edtNumber2.setText(setHeight + "");
   btn.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
}
```

Although if the case were slightly more complex (for example I wanted very similar parametrised functionality) it's often better to use an inner class which implements OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten your code, implement **OnClickListener** and add unimplemented method.

For each button set your event handler like this:

```
   btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Back in your **onClick() method** do something like this:

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId())
   {
   case R.id.btn:
                //TODO Code
                break;
   case R.id.btn2:
                break;    
    }

   }
```

This should solve your problem.